# Most effective way to transform Spark SQL DataFrame into a list of pojos

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assume you have the following Spark DataFrame extracted from Cassandra:

```
DataFrame df = cassandraSqlContext.sql(query);
```

with the following

```
+-----------------+------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|assetid          |tslice|deviceid         |value                                                |
+-----------------+------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|085eb9c6-8a16-...|201509|085eb9c6-8a16-...|Map(xval -> 120000, type -> xsd:double, yval -> 53.0)|
|085eb9c6-8a16-...|201509|085eb9c6-8a16-...|Map(xval -> 120000, type -> xsd:double, yval -> 53.0)|
|085eb9c6-8a16-...|201509|085eb9c6-8a16-...|Map(xval -> 120000, type -> xsd:double, yval -> 53.0)|
    ...
```

I would like to transform this DataFrame into a list of Java beans structured as follows

```
public class DataItem {
    private UUID assetID;
    private int tslice;
    private UUID deviceID;
    private Value value;

    // getters, setters...
}
```

and

```
public class Value {
    private double xval;
    private String type;
    private double yval;

    // getters, setters...
}
```

What is the best way to do that in Spark both in terms of performances and conciseness?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have access to the DataFrame and want to convert it to a list pojos, you should collect the dataframe and iterate the list of `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` to populate the list of pojos.

Or

You can use spark-cassandra connector which contains the methods to create JavaRDD which can be collected to get the list of pojos.

Code:

```
SparkContextJavaFunctions functions = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sparkContext);
JavaRDD<DataItem> cassandraRowsRDD = functions.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table_name",
                           CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(DataItem.class));
//required list of pojos
List<DataItem> = cassandraRowsRDD.collect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an RDD and then just map it into your classes.  This will return an rdd of those objects:

```
val dataItem = df.rdd.map(line => DataItem(line[0], line[1].toInt ...)
val value = df.rdd.map(line => Value(line[10].toDouble, ... )
```